# Best static site generator for dynamically created content

Tags: dynamic, static, generator, shopping-cart

Which Static Site Engine would make the most sense, if one was to make an online shop with dynamic content using e.g. Snipcart as the shopping cart? 
I hooked Snipcart up to Jekyll and I've seen implementations using other static site generators as well, but I'm thinking the generator should either be light (as in capable of building fast) and/or just able to build dynamically (which most really aren't).

By dynamic content I mean the site should update/refresh fairly often, depending on e.g. warehouse content (limited edition counter - only 10 items left, then 9 etc.) and timed offers (e.g. 12 hour sale of an item) ?

I took a look at **Broccoli-Taco** since it has "Dynamically generated pages based on data", but I've yet to get it working (not given up yet).

However, static site generators are very new to me and thus I've come to this place of great guru's and wanted to see if anyone here has any good input ?

Answer (score 2):

We've also had problems trying to use Broccoli-Taco for the first time this morning :confused: I work at Snipcart and we wanted to try it and see if we could maybe write a blog post about it.

However, we tried quite a few static site generators and we really love them ;) Here are some generators we liked:

- [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) is a static site generator written in Go, the compilation time is the fastest that we tried, and their documentation is awesome. I think it might be my favorite!
- [Roots](http://roots.cx/) is a static site generator in NodeJS, works very well, compilation is not as fast as Hugo but it still rules! Their documentation is also very well done and it's backed by [Carrot](http://carrot.is/), a nice agency in NYC so it should be more maintained than Broccoli-Taco.
- [Middleman](https://middlemanapp.com/) is a static site generator in Ruby, similar in some ways to Jekyll. Works very well!

We have blog posts on [Snipcart's blog](https://snipcart.com/blog) for each of those static site generators, they might be useful to get started:

- [Static Site E-Commerce: Integrating Snipcart with Middleman](https://snipcart.com/blog/static-site-e-commerce-integrating-snipcart-with-middleman)
- [Static Site E-Commerce (part 2): Integrating Snipcart with Jekyll](https://snipcart.com/blog/static-site-e-commerce-part-2-integrating-snipcart-with-jekyll)
- [Static Site E-Commerce (part 3): Integrating Snipcart with Hugo](https://snipcart.com/blog/static-site-e-commerce-part-3-integrating-snipcart-with-hugo)
- [Static Site E-Commerce (part 4): Integrating Snipcart with Roots](https://snipcart.com/blog/static-site-ecommerce-snipcart-roots-integration)

One last thing: you should really take a look at [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/). These guys are running an awesome service that makes static sites hosting a breeze! Whenever you push updates to your website, update your data files or anything, they will automatically redeploy your site in seconds! We used Netlify a lot and it really rocks.

Comment: Hi Charles - I already spoke with Georges and others at SnipCart. I'm doing a few web pages on Netlify already (still mostly just messing around) and got a Snipcart account as well already too. 
Tried out a few different static site generators so far, but since I'd also like Netlify CMS, I'd have to go with Jekyll, Pelican or Hexo, at least to get a template, but if I can get Matt to make one for e.g. Hugo, I'd love to write about it and test it, since it's the fastest.  On the other hand I've heard from @Jenius at roots and saw some of his video's and it also looks good. Will probably test...

Comment: Gotcha. If you end up writing about your experiences, we’d love to read them. We could maybe offer our blog as a platform if there’s a fit too. In any case, keep us posted!